# Multi-dimensional, convex and differentiable function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I want to test an optimization procedure for multi-dimensional, convex and differentiable functions. Could anyone refer me to some popular functions that fit these criterions?

Comment: $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \; \mapsto \; \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert^2$ ?

Comment: Thanks! However, I would like to test the performance of my optimization procedure on more examples, so additional suggestions are very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a matrix $H\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive semi-definite if $y^THy\geq 0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and positive definite if and only if $y^THy>0$ for all nonzero $y$.

Now consider the function $g_{x,y}(t)=f(x+ty)$, where $f$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x,y$ are fixed vectors.

The derivatives at $t=0$ are
$$g_{x,y}'(0) = y^T \nabla f(x), \qquad g_{x,y}''(0) = y^T \nabla^2 f(x) y$$
Of course if $g_{x,y}''(0)\geq 0$, then $g_{x,y}$ is convex at the origin. If $g_{x,y}''(0)\geq 0$ for all $y$, then $f$ is convex at $x$. Finally, if $g_{x,y}''(0)\geq 0$ for all $x,y$, then $f$ is convex.

These family of $g$'s can give one set of examples into the criteria you seek.